# PHP SQL Server decimal/numeric number can't starting with 0

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

I am using Laravel with database SQL Server my PHP version is 7.4 and my driver version 5.9.

I have a problem if the data is viewed from the Microsoft Management SQL Server database, numeric or decimal data types if we view data in database the result is 0.5, but when in Laravel I retrieve the query data the result is ,5 there is no 0 before decimal. is this a bug driver SQL Server?

[image: PICTURE IN DATABASE]

[image: Picture when I retrive data from query laravel]

For my query code Laravel.

```
 public function edit($id)
    {
        $tooling = DB::table('master_tooling')
        ->where('id',$id)->first();
        return view('setup.master_tooling.update',compact('tooling'));
    }
```

Comment: SQL Server has no control over the *display* format chosen by the application. The display format is determined by the presentation layer. You should be showing you PHP code here that is producing the values you don't want. Also, please don't litter your questions with *"Please help me!!"*; it is just noise (it doesn't add anything to the question), the exclamation marks (`!`) make it look like you are shouting, and [“Can someone help me?” isn't an actual question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: *"Is this a bug driver sql server?"* No.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't show leading zeros, so if you explicitly want to show zero on start save data in `VARCHAR` datatype and convert when you need `INT`. But think is this what you want before set to `VARCHAR`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP can convert the string`".23"` to a float, which will be represented correctly (`echo (float) '.23';` prints 0.23). All your `Laravel` columns are strings, `Laravel` has attribute casting, that will change the columns to the correct types.

Secondly, please use `Eloquent` models, that is what is considered best practice and way easier to work with than `DB::table()`. Create your model MasterTooling.php, you can create it with the following make command `php artisan make:model MasterTooling`. Here you can add the attribute casting, i only added `ton_max` and `ton_warn` to show.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class MasterTooling extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'ton_warn' => 'float',
        'ton_max' => 'float',
    ];
}
```

Your edit view code should now be updated to this.

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $tooling = MasterTooling::findOrFail($id);

    return view('setup.master_tooling.update',compact('tooling'));
}
```

Comment: Ok, we can deal with this...but if we have a query that returns a lot of fields, it's a pain to cast every one of them.

It must be a better way...

Answer (score 0):

In addition to mrhn's Answer you should check it out about SQL Driver in PHP and PDO options for all your queries with strings and all numeric types. Because in PHP according to Microsoft [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/default-php-data-types?view=sql-server-ver15).
Numeric and Floats for PHP are strings, but the trick there is the use of implicit cast:

`$float = (float) $floatStringVariable`

Why? Because those values are provided by the driver as [Numeric Strings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.numeric-strings.php)

Answer (score 0):

I was faced to this issue. According to [that](https://github.com/microsoft/msphpsql/issues/415), i used this option :

- **SQLSRV** : "FormatDecimals"=>true
- **PDO_SQLSRV** : PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_FORMAT_DECIMALS => true

After that, i've been getting "0.562" instead of ".562"

Comment: I tried that... but it continue giving me ".562"